# UTM coordinates in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, coordinates, utm

Is there a way to extract XY UTM coordinates, as a X,Y columns, in attribute table of a vector layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Geographic coordinates are possible to extract as X,Y using "Calculate geometry attributes".

Latitude and longitude in meters can be calculated using "Add XY coordinates".

I am wondering is there a way/functionality to extract X and Y in given UTM zone so one gets it as attribute fields of a layer?

Answer (score 1):

The [Calculate Geometry Attributes (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm) tool has a `coordinate_system` parameter that will let you calculate X,Y fields using a coordinate system other than that of your data.